# HTML5 required attribute trigger action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a prototype and I want to trigger an action after a submit but only if the required fields were filled.

I have this code

```
<button type="submit" onclick="doSomething()" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

And also an input on my form using the 'required' attribute from HTML 5, like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
```

I want to trigger the action onclick only if the input was filled.
I suppose I could do this by checking if the input was filled using jQuery, I was wondering if there is a simpler way

Comment: Is there a minimum length requirement for `input` element ?

Comment: Not really, it just needs to be filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have actually found a solution, if anyone is going through the same problem, this is how I did it.

Instead of using "onclick" on the button tag I added an "onsubmit" (I had no clue this existed) event inside my form tag with my doSomething function, like this:

```
<form onsubmit="doSomething()">
```

The function will only be called if the required inputs are filled, easy as that.

Thanks for the ones who tried to help anyway

Comment: If solution at post resolves Question , can "accept" own Answer , see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `oninput` event

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log("do stuff")
}

document.querySelector("input").oninput = function() {
  this.nextElementSibling.click()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
<button type="submit" onclick="doSomething()" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The "doSomething" function is triggered even if the required input is not filled. I have actually just found a solution, I will be posting now

Comment: @PedroBernardo _"It doesn't work. The "doSomething" function is triggered even if the required input is not filled."_ Why asked if there was required length for `input` element. If no required length , `doSomething` would be expected to be called even if input was space character `" "` . See comment at _"Not really, it just needs to be filled"_

Comment: But in your answer the doSomething function is triggered even with no space character.

Comment: @PedroBernardo _"But in your answer the doSomething function is triggered even with no space character."_ ? Cannot reproduce at stacksnippets above. `doSomething` should not be called until at least a single character is input at `input` element

Comment: @PedroBernardo _"I reproduce it at my own code"_ ? Can include "my own code" at Question ? , reproduce at stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? Where `oninput` event is triggered where no characters are input into `input` element ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always use this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/26/

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var content = $('input').val();

  if(content != '') {
    alert(content);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes sir, that would definitely solve it, but as I said on my question "I suppose I could do this by checking if the input was filled using jQuery, I was wondering if there is a simpler way". And I have actually found I simpler way, as my answer shows it. Thanks anyway